# React button onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

[image: My Code Screenshot]
[Error after using const history]

I am not able to use the history hook, even though I followed the same steps mentioned in the internet.Would really appreciate some help

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen'

import './MyStyles.css'


import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

function Home() {
    
   const history = useHistory();
  
    return (
            <div>

                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>CSS Website Layout</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div class="topnav">
                            <button>Home</button> &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
                            <button>Blog</button> &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
                            <button>Merchandise</button> &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
                            <button>About us</button>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
                            <button style={{float: 'right'}} onclick={()=> history.push("/LoginScreen")}>Sign Up!</button>
                        </div>
```

the error that I get is

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Comment: Add your minimal code, so we can help

Comment: Yes I have added it

Comment: `'./LoginScreen'` as well

Comment: Have you install react-router-dom in your application ? Execute this command to install it : `npm install --save react-router-dom`

Comment: Please post your `package.json` .

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are using onclick instead of onClick. onclick is ok while using html, but while using react use onClick.

And instead of using an inline function, create a separate function called handleClick and then call this function after clicking.

For more reference checkout this link - [React Router Dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you have forgotten to write the word const before history

Comment: After I used Const, i get this error, "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem."

Comment: sometimes the hot reloader is not working well do you refresh you page after update your code ?

Comment: This error says you need to update your React but be careful updating it will affect your entire project